# textScaleFactor is not using the center of my text as anchor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following function

```
      static Widget nameAvatar({String displayName, TextStyle style, double scale}) {
        final firstLetter = displayName.isNotEmpty ? displayName[0].toUpperCase() : '?';
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            firstLetter,
            style: style,
            textScaleFactor: 5.0,
          ),
        );
      }
```

Which returns a widget. I put this in a circle avatar. It's the fallback()

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (hasPhotoURL) precacheImage(_buildPhoto(), context);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => onTap?.call(),
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        radius: radius,
        backgroundImage: _buildPhoto(),
        child: ConditionalWidget(
          condition: !hasPhotoURL,
          builderTrue: () => fallback,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But my text seems to be scaling downwards? If I remove the textScaleFactor it is aligned perfectly in the center of the circle? It's almost as if the scaling is no being done from the center of the text. How can I get this letter in the center?

[image]

I use the following texttheme

```
  bodyText1: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14,
    color: _primaryColorLight,
    fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
  )
```

Comment: Try to set text height to 1

Comment: If I do that th letter J looks better aligned in the center but the letter M is beging scaled up also the letter B is scalled up.

Comment: If I remove the style it centers perfectly but it's no longer Open Sans